# Manual date entry check for jQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have jQuery datepicker on a page that allows manual date entry.How to check the format and validation of date in the jQuery UI Datepicker.For example,input 20030230,and it will remind me of the incorrect date.
thanks for your help.